# How to download Excel file from API when it returns href=cid

Tags: xml, api, soap, python-requests

I have this code. It works and returns a cid in href. But I am unable to see the downloaded file.

```
import requests

url = "https://www-genesis.destatis.de/genesisWS/web/DownloadService_2010?method=ExcelDownload&kennung=DEB924AL95&password=P@ssword123&name=42151-0002&bereich=Alle&komprimieren=false&transponieren=false&startjahr=1995&endjahr=2000&zeitscheiben=&regionalmerkmal=&regionalschluessel=&sachmerkmal=&sachschluessel=&sachmerkmal2=&sachschluessel2=&sachmerkmal3=&sachschluessel3=&auftrag=false&stand=&sprache=en"

payload = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"\r\nxmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"\r\nxmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"\r\nxmlns:web=\"http://webservice_2010.genesis\">\r\n <soapenv:Header/>\r\n <soapenv:Body>\r\n <web:ExcelDownload soapenv:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\">\r\n <kennung xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">DEB924AL95</kennung>\r\n <passwort xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">P@ssword123</passwort>\r\n <name xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">42151-0002</name>\r\n <bereich xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">Alle</bereich>\r\n <komprimieren xsi:type=\"xsd:boolean\">false</komprimieren>\r\n <transponieren xsi:type=\"xsd:boolean\">false</transponieren>\r\n <startjahr xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">1995</startjahr>\r\n<endjahr xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">2000</endjahr>\r\n <zeitscheiben xsi:type=\"xsd:string\"></zeitscheiben>\r\n <regionalmerkmal xsi:type=\"xsd:string\"></regionalmerkmal>\r\n <regionalschluessel xsi:type=\"xsd:string\"></regionalschluessel>\r\n <sachmerkmal xsi:type=\"xsd:string\"></sachmerkmal>\r\n <sachschluessel xsi:type=\"xsd:string\"></sachschluessel>\r\n <sachmerkmal2 xsi:type=\"xsd:string\"></sachmerkmal2>\r\n <sachschluessel2 xsi:type=\"xsd:string\"></sachschluessel2>\r\n <sachmerkmal3 xsi:type=\"xsd:string\"></sachmerkmal3>\r\n <sachschluessel3 xsi:type=\"xsd:string\"></sachschluessel3>\r\n <auftrag xsi:type=\"xsd:boolean\">false</auftrag>\r\n <stand xsi:type=\"xsd:string\"></stand>\r\n <sprache xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">de</sprache>\r\n </web:ExcelDownload>\r\n </soapenv:Body>\r\n</soapenv:Envelope>\r\n"
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/xml'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

This the Response got

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body>

<ExcelDownloadResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><ExcelDownloadReturn href="cid:9103D90118197A3862045E52ED8F1486"/></ExcelDownloadResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

The API Documentation says: „href“ points to the MS-Excel-file within the attachment of the SOAP-document.

How to view the downloaded file?

Comment: "returns a cid in href" - what does that mean? Can you share a sample of the response?

Comment: This was in the response. <ExcelDownloadReturn href="cid:9D6E643360AA5C9881795BCD17556CAC"/>

Comment: The API documentation says this: „href“ points to the MS-Excel-file within the attachment of the SOAP-document.

Comment: Best way is to save attachment to a file and then open attachment.  The attachment is MIME and is in the body of the response.  See following ample of MIME : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)?force_isolation=true

Comment: jdweng, could you please share any sample python code to demonstrate how to download file? I have never handled MIME

Comment: See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894923/extract-content-from-a-file-with-mime-multipart?force_isolation=true and https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch10s12.html?force_isolation=true